# how to pass parameter to show() method in resource controller from another function

Tags: php, laravel

I know that the route name for `show($id)` method is `some_name/parameter`.Here i have a login authentication mechanism and i want to show the user profile if the user passed the authentication.I have a function called `loginUser()` inside my `userController`.I want to redirect the user to user.show route on successful login.But i am not sure how to pass the parameter value to show method.Currently i am getting the error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: user.show] [URI: user/{user}].

**loginUser() function:**

```
public function loginUser(Request $request){

        $data = $request->all();

        $rules = array(
           'name' => 'required',
           'password'=>'required'
        );

        // Create a new validator instance.
        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
        if($validator->fails()){

            $errors=$validator->messages();
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);

        }else{

            if(Auth::attempt(['name'=>$request['name'],'password'=>$request['password']])){

                return redirect()->route('user.show')->with('name',$request['name']); // pass control to show() function
            }else{
                return redirect()->back()->with('data', 'wrong username or password');
            }
        }
    }
```

**show() method in userController:**

```
public function show($user)
{
    //
    $info=userModel::where('id','=',$user)->get(array('name'));
    return View::make('user.show')->with('name',$info);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your route `user.show` needs an id to determine which user to show. Like this:

```
redirect()->route('user.show', [$userId])->with(...);
```

If for example $userId is 1, this would resolve to the URI: user/1

If you want to show the user index, that's a different route.

Comment: thanks a lot :).. i don't need the with clause anymore i suppose ?

Comment: The with clause is used for message passing, so if you don't need it, no! More info is here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   redirect()->route('user.show', [$userId]);
```

you don't use `$name` in controller. remove `with` in redirect